# Passing information using HTML and Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm working on a uni project that involves logging films, sort of like Letterboxd. I've made a search page where users enter a keyword when looking for a movie, this then prints the results supplied by the tmdb api. Below is the code in my routes.py file for the search and results page:

```
@app.route('/search-movie', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def m_search():
    form = MovieSearch()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user_search = urllib.parse.quote(form.movieName.data)
        complete_url = search_url + user_search + "&page=1"
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(complete_url)
        json_data = json.loads(conn.read())
        return render_template('search_results.html', results=json_data["results"], term=form.movieName.data)
    return render_template('movie_search.html', form=form)
```

The following is the code in the html file for that page:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1> results for "{{term}}"</h1>
    <h2> click movie name to log it</h2>
        <div class="movie-list-container">
            {% for movie in results %}
            <div class="movie-card">
                <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}" alt="">
                <!-- <h3> {{movie.title}} ({{movie.release_date[:4]}})</h3> -->
                <h3><a class="log-link" href="{{ url_for('log_movie', movieid=movie.id) }}"> {{movie.title}} ({{movie.release_date[:4]}}) </a></h3>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see in the line I commented out, previously it would just display the movie title and release year. However I wanted to change is so that if the user presses the movie name, they are taken to a page where they add information through a form such as their rating, the date they watched the movie, and a review.
[This is how it's done on Letterboxd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/any2i.png) I wanted mine to be pretty much the same.

I want to be able to show the movie name, release date and poster for the movie they pressed on the logging page, and I tried this in the h3 by passing through movieid=movie.id . From there in my routes.py file I wrote the following code

```
@app.route('/log-movie', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log_movie(movieid):
    log_url = info_url + movieid + "?api_key=" + api_key
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(log_url)
    json_data = json.loads(conn.read())
    form = LogMovie()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        log_data = Diary(date_watched=form.dateWatched.data, movie_name=mname, release_date=myear, user_rating=form.movieRating.data, 
            rewatch=form.movieRewatch.data, review=form.movieReview.data, logger=current_user)
        db.session.add(log_data)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('log_movie.html', form=form, results=json_data["results"])
```

My idea was to simply get the movieid so that I can then request the information from the api again, so that I can pass it through like I did when displaying the results in the html code I added above.

When storing to the database, I have the variables mname, myear. These were from a previous attempt where I wished to pass in the movie year and release date from the HTML without needing to call upon the api again in routes.py. When I couldn't get the multiple variables to pass, that's when I changed it to just movieid. I forgot to change these back but should I manage to pass the information from the HTML, I may go back to this version.

I keep getting an error TypeError: log_movie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'movieid' and I can't seem to find an answer on google. I was wondering if anyone knew why, or a better way of achieving what I want?

I've never asked a question before so let me know if I need to provide more information.

Many Thanks! :)

Comment: Where do you get the error you mentioned? When you click on the movie name?

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/log-movie', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log_movie(movieid):
```

I'm just pointing out that. This is where your error is. If you want to get the movieid here, you're route should be

```
@app.route('/log-movie/<movieid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

In that way, if you GET /log-movie/12345, the movieid will be 12345.

Edit :
Just to be clear, i just pointed out where your error is, if you need more help about this, you can still make a comment, i'll edit my answer to other question :)